# cannot be cast to org.springframework.core.io.WritableResource on Spring AWS example

Tags: spring, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm reading this documentation:

http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-aws/spring-cloud-aws.html

on using AWS from a Spring application. I'm particularly interested in S3, so, I set up the application and copied this snippet of code to make sure the set up is working correctly:

```
Resource resource = this.resourceLoader.getResource("s3://myBucket/rootFile.log");
WritableResource writableResource = (WritableResource) resource;
try (OutputStream outputStream = writableResource.getOutputStream()) {
  outputStream.write("test".getBytes());
}
```

but when I run it, I get this error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextResource cannot be cast to org.springframework.core.io.WritableResource
```

Any ideas what's wrong? is that a setup problem? It doesn't look like to me, but I'm new to this.

Answer (score 3):

I had to remove

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

from my dependencies.

When devtools is included, inside the GenericApplicationContext.getResources() method it executes the if block, but without devtools it calls the super.getResource():

```
public Resource getResource(String location) {
    if (this.resourceLoader != null) {
        return this.resourceLoader.getResource(location);
    }
    return super.getResource(location);
}
```

This will use the s3 protocol handler and give you a different type of Resource that does implement WritableResource.

Comment: Commenting out `spring-boot-devtools` also worked for me. Thanks

Comment: I've tried this solution but without success. Using Spring Boot 2.1.7 e Spring Cloud Aws 2.1.4. I had to fix it using another approach. I'll post it here. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I've tried to follow the solution proposed by [@accresse](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1628183/accresse), but without success. My only way of solving it was declaring a new **`SimpleStorageProtocolResolver`** and adding it as a **`ProtocolResolver`** to the **`DefaultResourceLoader`**. Using Spring Boot 2.1.7 e Spring Cloud Aws 2.1.4.

```
@Autowired
public void configureResourceLoader(AmazonS3 amazonS3, DefaultResourceLoader resourceLoader) {
    SimpleStorageProtocolResolver simpleStorageProtocolResolver = new SimpleStorageProtocolResolver(amazonS3);
    // As we are calling it by hand, we must initialize it properly.
    simpleStorageProtocolResolver.afterPropertiesSet();
    resourceLoader.addProtocolResolver(simpleStorageProtocolResolver);
}
```

Links to follow:

- https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-aws/issues/348
- https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-aws/issues/384
- https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/9331

Comment: Thank you,  this has helped me with `Spring boot 2.3.1` and `spring-cloud-starter 2.2.2`. However, I'd still like to find out how to make the defaults to work.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue, turn out that I am using the wrong lib. Try to change dependency from

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-aws</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

To

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-aws</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Also do not forget to add aws config in application.yml, otherwise it won't start.

```
cloud.aws:
    region.static: your-region
    credentials:
      accessKey: your-key
      secretKey: your-secret
```

Hope this can solve your problem.

Answer (score -1):

Try declaring/casting Resource class as FileSystemResource instead:

```
FileSystemResource resource = this.resourceLoader.getResource("s3://myBucket/rootFile.log");
WritableResource writableResource = (WritableResource) resource;
try (OutputStream outputStream = writableResource.getOutputStream()) {
  outputStream.write("test".getBytes());
}
```