# Error creating bean with name 'amazonS3Client': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-aws

everything started because Spring Cloud AWS does not configure the **SimpleStorageProtocolResolver** correctly. This class is responsible for handling s3:// protocol while using a **ResourceLoader**. See issue for further details: [cannot be cast to org.springframework.core.io.WritableResource on Spring AWS example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47135265/cannot-be-cast-to-org-springframework-core-io-writableresource-on-spring-aws-exa/59078881#59078881).

So, I had to create it manually. But I'm also using the LocalStack solution (https://github.com/localstack/localstack), and as Spring Cloud AWS does not have an option to configure the Endpoint manually, I had (guess what?) to create the **AmazonS3Client** by hand.

Here comes the problem, when I create both beans in my class **S3Configuration** class (see below), Spring Framework just skips the bean creation. And, when I try to wire it on the **S3Handler** class (see below), this error happens: *Error creating a bean with name '**amazonS3Client**': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?*

But again, here comes the whole thing, there is no circular reference between those classes.

I have simplified the project so I would be able to post it here:

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.7.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>
    <groupId>io.mobi7.ms</groupId>
    <artifactId>mobi7-temp-ms-ibutton-worker</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <spring-cloud-version>2.1.4.RELEASE</spring-cloud-version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-aws</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-cloud-version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

S3Configuration.java

```
package io.mobi7.ms.ibutton.worker;

import com.amazonaws.auth.AWSCredentialsProvider;
import com.amazonaws.client.builder.AwsClientBuilder;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3ClientBuilder;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.cloud.aws.core.io.s3.SimpleStorageProtocolResolver;
import org.springframework.cloud.aws.core.region.RegionProvider;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.io.DefaultResourceLoader;

@Configuration
public class S3Configuration {

    @Bean("amazonS3Client") // THIS METHOD IS NOT BEING CALLED!!!
    public AmazonS3 amazonS3Client(AWSCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider,
                                   RegionProvider regionProvider,
                                   @Value("${cloud.aws.s3.default-endpoint}") String endpoint) {
        return AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
            .withCredentials(credentialsProvider)
            .withEndpointConfiguration(
                new AwsClientBuilder.EndpointConfiguration(endpoint, regionProvider.getRegion().getName()))
            .build();
    }

    @Autowired  // THIS METHOD IS NOT BEING CALLED!!!
    public void configureResourceLoader(@Qualifier("amazonS3Client") AmazonS3 amazonS3Client,
                                        DefaultResourceLoader resourceLoader) {
        SimpleStorageProtocolResolver simpleStorageProtocolResolver = new SimpleStorageProtocolResolver(amazonS3Client);
        // As we are calling it by hand, we must initialize it properly.
        simpleStorageProtocolResolver.afterPropertiesSet();
        resourceLoader.addProtocolResolver(simpleStorageProtocolResolver);
    }
}
```

S3Handle.java

```
package io.mobi7.ms.ibutton.worker;

import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.S3ObjectSummary;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

@Component
public class S3Handler {

    private AmazonS3 amazonS3Client;

    @Autowired
    public S3Handler(@Qualifier("amazonS3Client") AmazonS3 amazonS3Client) {
        this.amazonS3Client = amazonS3Client;
    }

    public List<String> listFiles(String bucketName) {
        return amazonS3Client.listObjects(bucketName).getObjectSummaries().stream().map(S3ObjectSummary::getKey)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

Application.java

```
package io.mobi7.ms.ibutton.worker;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.WebApplicationType;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SpringApplicationBuilder(Application.class).web(WebApplicationType.NONE).run(args);
    }

    @Autowired
    public void listFiles(S3Handler s3Handler) {
        s3Handler.listFiles("default-s3-bucket").forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

application.properties

```
cloud.aws.region.static=us-east-1
cloud.aws.stack.auto=false
cloud.aws.s3.default-endpoint=http://localhost:4572
```

Any ideas, why is this happening?

Comment: The problem is partially because you are doing everything configuration time. I suggest instead of your `Application.listFiles` method, to create an `@Bean` method that returns an `ApplicationRunner` to do the same. This should delay the creation and give proper time to construct the objects.

Comment: It makes senes but the listFiles method was created just to simplify the question here, even if I insert the S3Handler in a @RestController, the same error occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@Autowired` annotation marks a method that constructs object state (e.g. setter or method injection). See "Autowired Methods" section [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Autowired.html).

Both methods that you annotated with Autowired are not used for this need.

This question is about Spring. All other tags can be removed.

---

**Update:** Similar case is covered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28748366/1262265).
Regardless of what is suggested there, I would not keep a single GOD configuration class, instead I would split your configuration class into 2 classes - factory for S3 client and configuration of resource loader.

Comment: I disagree, the method configureResourceLoader in class S3Configuration is a config method. I need to reconfigure the DefaultResourceLoader. And in the documentation that you have passed, says that I can do it in a config method: "Config methods may have an arbitrary name and any number of arguments; each of those arguments will be autowired with a matching bean in the Spring container".

Comment: The second @autowired method it was created just to simplify the solution. Spring should have created/autowired in this order: S3Configuration.amazonS3Client, S3Configuration.configureResourceLoader, S3Handler.S3handler, Application.listFiles. I don't know why but if remove the Qualifier from configureResourceLoader method it works perfectly. Which not make senes at all.

Comment: @FelipeDesiderati This is covered here https://stackoverflow.com/a/28748366/1262265 I updated the answer

Comment: Thaaaaaaaaanks, it makes more sense now.